# casting and the copy_to_user macro

Tags: c, casting, linux-kernel

I need to copy `curr_task->pid`, a `pid_t` in kernel space, to a structure's field in user space that has space for a long. Since this is a widening conversion, I'm not expecting any issues.

However, I'm getting an annoying compiler warning (`copy_long_to_user` is for all intents and purposes the same as `copy_to_user`):

```
cs300/process_ancestors.c:31:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘copy_long_to_user’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   if(copy_long_to_user(&info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid, &curr_task->pid)) {    
   ^
cs300/process_ancestors.c:9:5: note: expected ‘long int *’ but argument is of type ‘pid_t *’
```

Is this warning something I can safely ignore (will the compiler do the cast for me)? If I need to cast `curr_task->pid` to a long explicitly, how can I do that in the context of using `copy_to_user`? My guess would be that it's something like:`(copy_long_to_user(&info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid, &((long)curr_task->pid)))`

Comment: I hope you didn't just take part of @ChunleiMa's answer and make the type of the second parameter of  `copy_long_to_user()` a `void*`.

Comment: Nope, the answer made me realize what I was doing wrong though -- I was telling `copy_to_user` to copy 8 bytes when there was only 4 bytes of data in the source location.

Comment: I thought that perhaps a shortcut like I mentioned might have been what cause you other , related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658863/printing-pid-with-d-vs-ld-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux kernel, the type of pid_t is equals to int, so the compiler warns you that `int*` cannot cast to `long int*`.
I don't know how do you realize your `copy_long_to_user` function, if you write like this, you may get a wrong result.

`copy_long_to_user(long int* dest, long int* src){
    copy_to_user(dest, src, sizeof(long int));
    ......
}`

because `sizeof(long)` >= `sizeof(int)`, if `sizeof(long)` > `sizeof(int)`, support that `sizeof(long) == 8`, and `sizeof(int) always 4`, you will get a wrong result, because `current_task->pid` just occupy the 4 byte of `dest`, but `copy_to_user(dest, src, sizeof(long int))` must copy 8 byte to dest, so the 4 bytes follow the `current->pid` are copied to `dest`, so `dest` can not equal to `current->pid`.
so you'd better write a function named `copy_pid_to_user` and it codes like that:

`copy_pid_to_user(long int* dest, void* src){
    copy_to_user(dest, src, sizeof(curent->pid))
    ......`

Answer (score 4):

You need a helper variable to do this correctly.

```
long curr_pid = curr_task->pid;
copy_long_to_user(&info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid, &curr_pid);
```

Taking the address of a helper variable is legal, address of a temporary (produced by the cast) isn't.