# printing pid with %d vs %ld, linux

Tags: c, linux, casting, printf

I'm storing a series of `pid`s (i.e. Linux process ids) in an array of `long`s. I realize that a `pid` is not a `long`, but I have no choice in terms of using a different variable type.

The issue I'm having occurs when I try and print the `pid` using `printf`. If I print the `long` that stores the `pid` using `%ld`, I get the wrong pids:

```
8435315771308 process_ancesto
8358006359962 bash
8353711392665 login
4294967297 init
0 swapper/0
```

However, if I print using `%d` (which generates a compiler warning), I get the correct result (i.e. the result returned by typing `ps` into the terminal):

```
1969 process_ancesto
1946 bash
1945 login
1 init
0 swapper/0
```

What is causing this behaviour? A pid -> long cast is a widening conversion and shouldn't cause any problems.

Here is the program I use to make the system call that returns the pids:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct process_info arr[10];
    long n=0;
    int result = syscall(_CS300_PROCESS_ANCESTORS_, arr,10,&n);
    assert(result==0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n",arr[i].pid,arr[i].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I replace the `%d` with `%ld` it prints incorrect info.

Here is the line from my system call where I record the `pid`:

```
if(copy_long_to_user(&info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid, &curr_task->pid)) {                
            return -EFAULT;
        }
```

`info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid` is a long.

Comment: Show us a full but minimal working sample program which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: What kind of machine are you using (Intel? 32 or 64 bit?) -- tells us more about your envirionment.

Comment: Intel, 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

In your `copy_to_user`, the second argument is a pointer to `pid_t`, it appears, which as you say is an `int` (32 bits).  So you are copying 64 bits from a 32-bit variable; the remaining 32 bits (the high half, since x86 is little-endian) will be filled with whatever came next in memory, if you are lucky.  (If you are unlucky you get a fault here.)  Integer conversions aren't done when you access things via pointers.

The simplest way to do this safely is to use a temporary variable:

```
long tmp = curr_task->pid; // sign-extension done here
copy_long_to_user(..., &tmp);
```

Then in your user space code, you are using the `%d` format specifier to print something that's apparently a `long`.  This won't work; `printf`, being a variadic function, doesn't know the type that its arguments are expected to have, and so can't convert them appropriately.  If you're going to pass a `long`, use the `%ld` format specifier.

Comment: [I agree with the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36658968/103167), but that isn't a "temporary".

Comment: @BenVoigt: To be grammatical I should have said "temporary variable".  I meant it in the informal sense of the word, ["a variable whose purpose is short-lived"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_variable), not in any formal language-standard sense.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, I see that was a previous question by the same user.  Awkward that they overlapped this way.

Comment: Would a cast also work? I.e. `copy_long_to_user(... , &((long)curr_task->pid))`

Comment: @Adam: As Ben Voigt explained in his answer to your other question, no it will not.  [The result of a cast isn't an lvalue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389579/634919) and you can't take its address.  (Some old versions of gcc supported something like this as an extension, but it's non-standard and can't be expected to work these days.)

Comment: Why do programmers so often reach for a cast when they're not even sure exactly what it does?

Comment: Why don't I need to cast `curr_task->pid` when it's assigned to tmp?

Comment: Because the compiler can perform an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`.

Answer (score 2):

> A pid -> long cast is a widening conversion and shouldn't cause any problems.

Sure, but unless you're actually performing said cast it won't happen, at least not with varargs/stdargs. Either cast the argument yourself or use the correct specifier.

Comment: What happens if I cast something and then use the address operator on it? That's what I think I need to do with `copy_to_user`. How can one address refer to two different variable types?

Comment: You need to think of casts and address/dereference operators as no-ops; they change the type for the C compiler, but in the vast majority of cases they don't affect the data in any way.

Comment: So if I cast a `pid` to a long, the underlying "pid-ness" of the `pid` variable doesn't change. The cast just allows us to fit a copy of the pid variable into a long-type variable.

Comment: It tells the compiler that it should treat it as a 64-bit value instead of a 32-bit value. If something other than 0 is in the other 32 bits then you get results similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at your numbers as hex numbers

```
8358006359962 bash
```

is in hex

```
79A0000079A
```

and

```
1946 bash
```

is in hex

```
79A
```

So guessing here -- but you have done something bad when you converted the numbers into long longs in `copy_long_to_user`, since the 79A sequence repeats in the higher bits.

Answer (score 2):

So the pid is copied into the output array using:

```
copy_long_to_user(&info_array[num_filled_kernel].pid, &curr_task->pid)
```

If `curr_task` is a `struct task_struct*`, then `curr_task->pid` is an `int`, which is 4 bytes on Linux (whether 32 or 64 bits).  However `long` on 64-bit Linux is 8 bytes, so you end up copying not only the pid, but 4 other adjacent bytes (which are probably the `tgid` - I don't know exactly what that is, but it looks like it often has the same value as the pid).

Update:  the `tgid` is a Thread Group ID, and it does often have the same value as the pid:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306150/12711